# Linux permissions when files are written/read by different processes

Tags: linux, permissions, nginx, tomcat

I have a Web application deployed via Tomcat that allows upload of files in a dir `files`. These files are uploaded by Tomcat with owner `tomcat:tomcat` and permissions `640`. I need to mantain the group `tomcat` because other users need it for administration purposes.

On the download side, I have a Nginx that supplies the files for users.

The problem is that Nginx cannot access the uploaded files, because it uses a user `www-data:www-data`.

- I cannot add `www-data` to the group `tomcat` for security reasons.
- I cannot substitute `tomee` group for `www-data`, because I need the
  `tomee` group and I cannot let tomee create ALL files under the
  `www-data` group (f.ex. tomee would create logs under
  `tomee:www-data`, which is undesired - only the uploads in any case
  could have this)
- I cannot let `others` have any permissions on the files, for security reasons. In any case I cannot change the default `640` Tomcat mask because (bad Tomcat design?) it would affect EVERY file that Tomcat creates.
- I could use `chmod g+s` but this does not seem to affect the files recursively (Tomcat creates also directories in which it then uploads the file)

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have solved it but need to do more testing before accepting the solution.

- `sudo apt install acl`  (based on Ubuntu)
- `sudo chown tomcat:www-data files`
- `sudo chmod g+s files`
- `sudo setfacl -Rm d:g:www-data:r files`